# How to create a image button menu programmatically?

Tags: java, android, image, layout

I want to make a menu like this:
[image: Banjo Layout]

The images and text will be loaded from internet. Which approach do you suggest me to use? Should i use a grid layout? Or an adapter? Do you know what this kind of layout is called? And do you have any examples of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a holder for the image just the link to the displayed image changes.

Comment: Listview with custom adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a ListView with a custom Adapter to provide the functionality, and for the image-downloading, i would suggest using the Picasso library. It handles downloading images async and also handles errors very well, i've never had issues with it and its extremely simple.

Link to Picasso: square.github.io/picasso/